# How to get a $ sign in an input field without it counting toward the value

Tags: jquery

I've got a really simple jQuery calculator setup. I've pasted the script and HTML below if it's helpful.

It works perfectly, but I'd like to insert a $ before the actual content of the value. So in the script below, you can enter 100 into the first field, and it'll show you what 10% off of $100 / month for 3 years is. I just need to *display* the dollar sign, not actually add it to the value if that's easier...

I do also want to make sure the functionality below whereby only numbers can be entered is retained.

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<form id="savings-calculator" action="#">
    <label>Your monthly premium:</label>
    <input id="premium-amount" name="premium" type="number" value="333" />
    <label>Your three year savings:</label>
    <input id="three-year-savings" class="circle secondary-circle" name="three-year-savings" type="text" value="1200" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#premium-amount').bind('keypress keydown keyup change',function(){
    var premium = parseFloat($(':input[name="premium"]').val(),10)
    var v = '';

    if (!isNaN(premium)){

        v = (premium * 36) * (0.10);
    }

    $(':input[name="three-year-savings"]').val(v.toString());
});    

});
</script>
```

Comment: Give the input a padding-left, then place the $ in a span that's floated over the input. Might also help to have the span's click event cause focus on the input.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why the three-year-savings element is an input field if it is just going to store a calculated value..  Also is there some reason, you just don't put a `$` in the HTML next to the field?

Comment: `$(':input[name="three-year-savings"]').val( '$' + v.toString());`

Comment: Thanks @CDspace. How do I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: @MikeBrant it's all due to the style, the input fields don't really look like input fields so much in the end but will eventually be used for submitting a form...so right now they're big circles with the values inside and I want the $ to line up with the ### itself and not on the outside of the circle.

Comment: @KevinB the values will range from 1 to 1,000 or more, and text is centered in the style of the field, so positioning the $ somehow to know where in the vertical flow of things to hang out would be a bit trickier I think than figuring out how to put the $ in as part of the actual value.

Comment: @Nathan I added an answer you can accept. I also added a few more comments that might help later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add it to the string you're putting in the control, and leave the computed value alone, like so:

```
$(':input[name="three-year-savings"]').val( '$' + v.toString());
```

Note that when you pull the value from the control, it will have the `$` in it, while `v` will remain unchanged. If you need to use the value from the control, you can simply use `replace` before you use `parseFloat`

```
v = parseFloat( $(':input[name="three-year-savings"]').val().replace( '$', '' ) );
```